# SQL Injection vulnerability testing

Tags: javascript, testing

What is the best way to verify SQL Injection vulnerability of page input's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this answer **does not** explain every breach! It only explains the two most common.

### Protect against [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

SQL Injection is injection of SQL in a query to modify its behaviour.
Example: Insert `' OR 'a' = 'a` in a HTML input to avoid typing password.

To protect against it you should escape strings.

An SQL Query is just a string, so you can do something like that:

```
<?php
$value = "blue";
$query = "select * from table where column = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
```

Explanations:
The value of variable $value is set in $query. But if there is no more security, it is possible to do a SQL Injection. So, I'm using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). But, if you want to insert value if variable, you should prefer [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Exemple of prepared statement using PDO (from documentation):

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = :name");
$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));
$allResults = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

See [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to know which constant to use.

To protect youself against some common attacks, you can use frameworks that manage the most common (Ex [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) or other).

### Protect against [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (Cross-Site Scripting)

XSS is the art of executing some code on target website. Example :

You fill a form (input or textarea) and instead of your name you type javascript code inside, like:

```html
<script>
  alert('xss');  
</script>
```

If XSS attack worked, you should see a popup in your browser when the website try to display this value.

#### To protect yourself against XSS

The first rule is **Never Trust User Input**. So, every time a user type something in a form, or any information that comes from user, should be treated in unsafe. Because informations are unsafe, you should escape them before display.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($value);
```

See [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Also, you can use a template engine, like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) that escapes automatically variables.

Comment: What value/(code initiation) in edit field (php) could get error?

Comment: In these cases, you code should not crash. But if your variable `$name` has a value that not match in database, you'll just not find anything. `$allResults` could be an empty array. Have I right understood what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes fine, now i need just JavaScript example. Maybe text like `document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "error!";)` in edit field will crash a script?

Comment: Please rewrite your question a little bit, I do not understand what you are looking for. You have an SQL query that resists to SQL injection, but what error are you speaking?

Comment: I edited question a little bit.

Comment: In my answer I show to you how to **protect** a website from SQL Injection and from crashing due to that. You are looking for XSS, but I will not show you how to crash a website, you should search on a hacking forum.

Comment: I need this to protected my website from errors.

Comment: I edited answer to explain you how to protect your website about two common attack (so you'll can test it)